# How to set rounded corner of TextSpan in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

I want to set rounded corner of Textspan in flutter, I think class `Paint` is needed, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(),
        body: new RichText(
          text: new TextSpan(
            text: null,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              new TextSpan(
                text: 'inactive ',),
              new TextSpan(
                  text: 'active',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    background: Paint()
                      ..color = Colors.redAccent,
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a way to use Textspan to achieve that instead of using a `Container` wrapping `Text`?

Answer (score 11):

Without using `Container` or something else - I can see only one way to make corners rounded

```
TextSpan(
    text: 'active',
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 20.0,
        color: Colors.white,
        background: Paint()
          ..strokeWidth = 24.0
          ..color = Colors.red
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeJoin = StrokeJoin.round))
```

But in this case there are paddings around text, so I doubt this is proper way

Comment: If I set strokeWidth = 1, the border is no visible. Can I config the border radius?

Comment: It seems you can't. As I said - I doubt this is proper way, because it's hardly customize.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe need a Stack and calculate position as a workaround.

Comment: I wish we have “PiantingStyle.both”.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RichText` with `WidgetSpan`, then combine it with line height

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Container(
          child: Text(
            addressItem.deliveryAddressType == "home" ? "Nhà" : "Văn phòng",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: AppFonts.SFUITextMedium,
              color: AppColors.wram_grey,
              fontSize: AppFonts.textSizeSmall,
            ),
          ),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppColors.header_grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 2, 6, 2),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
        ),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: '${addressItem.street}, ${addressItem.ward}, ${addressItem.city}, ${addressItem.region}',
        style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: AppFonts.SFUITextMedium,
            color: AppColors.wram_grey,
            fontSize: AppFonts.textSizeMedium,
            height: 1.5),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if the highlighted text is short enough (so you do not want to break line in it), you can just use WidgetSpan insted of TextSpan.

For example:

```
RichText(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            text: TextSpan(
              children: [
                TextSpan(
                  text: "some text",
                ),
                WidgetSpan(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 1),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(999),
                    ),
                    child: IntrinsicWidth(
                      child: Text(
                        "some text",
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ),
                TextSpan(text: "some text"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a package which is able to customize the background of the text --> you can change the radius, padding and color for the text background.

It's a fork from the AutoSizeText widget so you could even autosize the text if you want to.

Here is an example image of the text with background, radius and padding.
[image]

Hope this can help anyone who needs it.

The link to the github repo is following: https://github.com/Letalus/auto_size_text_background

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set the rounded corner of the text field in Flutter You have to use Container only, If you want to avoid Container then there is another way, you have to avoid using ListView as a body in your app. If you want to add an only single item on screen then you can try without container but if there is more than one item then you have no choice without implementing ListView and add multiple containers for a different purpose.

```
new Container(
              height: 80.0,
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                          topRight: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                          bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(30.0),
                          bottomRight: const Radius.circular(30.0))),
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new Text("Active text"),
                  )),
            ),
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it's gonna work. But in my application, I need to make each word(split by space) in a article clickable. However, if I create one `Text` for each word, chances are that in some lines, the first word on that line is space therefore there is no alignment at the start. [example](https://i.imgur.com/A4nxE3A.png)

Comment: To avoid space at the start or end of the text, you can use **trim()** which will help you to trim the extra spaces from the string. Will not it work?

Comment: I'm using `Wrap(children: articleStr.split(' ').map((w) => Text(w)).toList())` I don't know how which line's first component is a `Text` with space as content.